# Inner joining 2 tables on their index columns AND their non-index columns

Tags: python, pandas, join, indexing, combinatorics

**Problem:**
I have two pandas dataframes of ~3GB each, to join on 1) postcode & 2) every combination of house_identifier variables until either a row has found a join (in a for loop) or all variable-to-variable combinations have failed for the row.

After two columns have joined a row in the loop, that row will be appended to a separate list and removed from the dataframes. *postcode* is a non-unique index.

**Table columns (not hirarchical)**

dataset_1 has these variables: 
*postcode, house_identifier_1, house_identifier_2, house_identifier_3, id*

dataset_2 has these variables:
*postcode, house_identifier_a, house_identifier_b, id_2*

**Column combinations to join in a loop:**

```
table_1_variables = ['number_x', 'number_y', 'number_z']
table_2_variables = ['number_a', 'number_b']
for i in table_1_variables:
    for j in table_2_variables:
```

To join the tables efficiently a stratgy seems to be to first join on the indexes (postcodes), and then on the non-indexed columns. However it seems like this would create a very large intermediary join which would push an 8GB memory over limits and the syntax is also unclear between combining (left_index=True, right_index=True, left_on=, right_on=)

Meanwhile, indexing/reindexing and then sorting_index inside a loop seems very inefficient.
Is there a better way to join or merge theese efficiently?

**Example of intersects:**

```
{'id': {27: '{582D0636-8DEF-8F22-E053-6C04A8C01BAC}',
  41: '{D9E869FE-7B55-4C36-AC43-695B9033A13B}',
  33: '{93E6821E-554E-40FD-E053-6B04A8C0C1DF}',
  1: '{288DCE29-0589-E510-E050-A8C06205480E}',
  48: '{3A23DDD5-A0E8-41D2-A514-5B09385C301F}',
  52: '{CEB16957-F7FA-4D1B-B45F-A390214735BC}',
  13: '{404A5AF3-9B20-CD2B-E050-A8C063055C7B}',
  16: '{64342BFD-FD07-422C-E053-6C04A8C0FB8A}',
  57: '{29A8E769-8A10-4477-9494-FF55EF5FAE4B}',
  10: '{404A5AF3-0B58-CD2B-E050-A8C063055C7B}',
  21: '{55BDCAE6-0C10-521D-E053-6B04A8C0DD7A}',
  31: '{5C676A02-1781-4152-950C-6E5CA2CBC487}',
  7: '{68FEB20B-142E-38DA-E053-6C04A8C051AE}',
  45: '{8F1B26BD-673F-53DB-E053-6C04A8C03649}',
  12: '{2F115F7A-8F81-4124-9FD4-FB76E742B2C1}',
  36: '{344AB2D7-4B59-4AB4-8F52-75B29BE8C509}',
  20: '{965B6D91-D4B6-95E4-E053-6C04A8C07729}',
  56: '{59872FD9-F39D-4BB9-95F6-91E002D948B1}',
  22: '{6141DFF0-973F-4FEC-A582-7F310B566031}'},
 'id_2': {27: 10002277489,
  41: 64023255,
  33: 10007367447,
  1: 22229221,
  48: 10033235735,
  52: 100062162615,
  13: 50103744,
  16: 10022903998,
  57: 12015624,
  10: 12154940,
  21: 10024247587,
  31: 100041193990,
  7: 10008230730,
  45: 10091640210,
  12: 202107394,
  36: 5062293,
  20: 48114659,
  56: 10001311242,
  22: 10000443154},
 'postcode': {27: 'lu72la',
  41: 'cf626nt',
  33: 'hr40aq',
  1: 'bn32pd',
  48: 'sg13ae',
  52: 'gu97jx',
  13: 'ct202ef',
  16: 'bh14rn',
  57: 'ub24af',
  10: 'w55bu',
  21: 'po302dp',
  31: 'tq148aq',
  7: 'e82ag',
  45: 'ch47ew',
  12: 'ha90ae',
  36: 'nw34tt',
  20: 'sw192rw',
  56: 'so143hw',
  22: 'se218hp'},
 'house_identifier_1': {27: '76',
  41: 'flat6',
  33: '49',
  1: 'flat10',
  48: '145',
  52: '31',
  13: 'flat19',
  16: 'flat7',
  57: '76',
  10: 'flat1',
  21: 'flat1',
  31: 'flat43',
  7: 'flata',
  45: '8',
  12: '42',
  36: 'flat9',
  20: 'flat43',
  56: 'flat156',
  22: 'flat2'},
 'house_identifier_2': {27: 'eastdock',
  41: 'courtlands',
  33: 'watkinscourt',
  1: 'ascothouse',
  48: 'monumentcourt',
  52: 'sumnercourt',
  13: '22-24',
  16: '77',
  57: 'osterleyviews',
  10: '55-59',
  21: '138',
  31: 'leandercourt',
  7: '130',
  45: 'greenbankhall',
  12: 'danescourt',
  36: 'holmefieldcourt',
  20: 'bennetscourtyard',
  56: 'oceanaboulevard',
  22: '124f'},
 'house_identifier_3': {27: 'eastdock',
  41: 'courtlands',
  33: 'watkinscourt',
  1: 'ascothouse',
  48: 'monumentcourt',
  52: 'sumnercourt',
  13: None,
  16: None,
  57: 'osterleyviews',
  10: None,
  21: None,
  31: 'leandercourt',
  7: None,
  45: 'greenbankhall',
  12: 'danescourt',
  36: 'holmefieldcourt',
  20: 'bennetscourtyard',
  56: 'oceanaboulevard',
  22: None},
 'house_identifier_a': {27: None,
  41: None,
  33: None,
  1: '18-20',
  48: None,
  52: None,
  13: '22-24',
  16: '77',
  57: None,
  10: '55-59',
  21: '138',
  31: None,
  7: '130',
  45: None,
  12: None,
  36: None,
  20: None,
  56: None,
  22: '124f'},
 'house_identifier_b': {27: '76',
  41: 'flat6',
  33: '49',
  1: 'flat10',
  48: '145',
  52: '31',
  13: 'flat19',
  16: 'flat7',
  57: '76',
  10: 'flat1',
  21: 'flat1',
  31: 'flat43',
  7: 'flata',
  45: '8',
  12: '42',
  36: 'flat9',
  20: 'flat43',
  56: 'flat156',
  22: 'flat2'}}
```

Comment: I would really consider breaking the datasets into postcodes by groupby and then doing the joins pushing the matches out to the combined matching file.  Also, I would recommend that you push things to intermediary disks.  Doing all this in memory sounds like a bad idea. 
This will lead to the fastest combine but have more coding to get there.

Comment: That sounds ok - so you're saying that instead of append to list, concatenate to a CSV. And also remove the results from that loop stage from dataset_1 and dataset_2. That makes sense - I assumed that because it was only 3 cols it wouldn't be too heavy on memory, but am likely wrong.

How would you handle the combine itself with regards to indexing?

Comment: I thougth that you would then use the loop to merge the postcode matched files and then dump the matches into a matched file for that item.  Then merge the match list by postcode.  The idea is to keep the variable matching withing the groups that it can match only...

Comment: Aaah, I see. Yes, you're right - the challenge is that this is a simplified problem, and in reality there are over 50 columns in each table (so the number of files would be painfully high in a scaled situation).